# MUI DRAWER: How do I override the theme?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

In this example, I would like to override the theme.

I want to understand where the theme returned from `useTheme()` hook is accessed from.

Because, when I add a theme to the top level or in the same file as mui drawer, it lacks properties such as `theme.typography` and `theme.zIndex.drawer` that the drawer depends on and the app crashes.

Any ideas for how to inherit properties needed or change just a few would be immensely helpful.

Here is a link to the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dvh1g?file=/demo.js)

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import AppBar from './components/material-ui/AppBar';
import {createTheme, ThemeProvider} from '@mui/system';
//apply theme to content, AppBar, have styeld div in AppBar
let theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#0000ff',
    },
    background: {
      paper: '#fff',
    },
    text: {
      primary: 'blue',
      secondary: 'red',
    },
    action: {
      active: '#001E3C',
    },
    success: {
      dark: '#009688',
    },
  },
});

function App() {

  return (
      <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <AppBar color='primary'/>
          </header>
          <div className = "slide"></div>
      </div>


  );
}

export default App;
```

AppBar.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import logo from '../imgs/Symboltm_FirstKey_01.jpg';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import AdminPanelSettingsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AdminPanelSettings';
import AutoGraphIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AutoGraph';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import Image from '.././imgs/Symboltm_FirstKey_01.jpg'
import Card from './Card';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Content from '../../routes/ContentRoutes.js';


const drawerWidth = 240;

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #000c19 30%, #004999 90%)',
    // border: 0,
    // borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 75,
  },
});

const openedMixin = (theme) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(9)} + 1px)`,
  },
});

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
    }),
  }),
);

export default function MiniDrawer() {
  console.log('theme before: ' + JSON.stringify(theme));
  const theme = useTheme();
  console.log('theme after: ' + JSON.stringify(theme));
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar className = {classes.root} position="fixed" open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{
              marginRight: '36px',
              ...(open && { display: 'none' }),
            }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <img src={logo} width = "100" style = {{paddingTop: '2.5px'}} alt="Logo"/>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
        <DrawerHeader>

          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            <h5>First Key Mortgage</h5>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <List>
          {['Dashboards', 'Account Settings'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <AutoGraphIcon /> : <AdminPanelSettingsIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
        <br/>
        <h1> Welcome </h1>
        <Card style={{backgroundColor: "red"}} sx={{bgColor: 'blue'}}/>
        <br></br>
        <Item/>
        <br></br>
        <Item/>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non
          enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Risus at ultrices mi tempus
          imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus.
          Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices.
          Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit
          adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra
          nibh cras. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum
          leo. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis
          feugiat vivamus at augue. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at
          consectetur lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem donec massa
          sapien faucibus et molestie ac.
        </p>
        <p>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est ullamcorper
          eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim
          neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra
          tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris. Elementum eu facilisis
          sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio. Morbi
          tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. In hendrerit
          gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem
          et tortor. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis
          tristique sollicitudin nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis
          eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla
          posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
        </p>
        <Content/>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The object returned from the `useTheme` hook is the default Mui theme. If you want to customise it, you need to use `createTheme` and pass the result to a `<ThemeProvider />` component that wraps over the whole application. `createTheme` by default creates the default theme with all of its props, but accepts overrides to absolutely everything.

Refer to [the Mui docs on theming](https://mui.com/customization/theming/) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense that it's default. When I've been trying to use createTheme() at the top level it gets overridden by the hooks call to useTheme() in the example above; Is there a way to make sure the createTheme() content modifications are included in the call to useTheme(); because they don't seem show up on the page. Simple ones like text.primary and text.secondary?

Comment: @BrandonBell it gets overridden because you forgot to pass it in a `ThemeProvider` that wraps over the app.

Comment: No unfortunately not I used <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> </ThemeProvider> in my app in App.js which wraps the AppBar as a component import. When I do this, the theme cannot find property dependencies such as theme.typography and theme.zIndex

Comment: @brandonbell May I look at the code?

Comment: yes just posted... going with the useTheme() hook overrides my code... I'm not sure I've been getting weird behavior with buttons too at layers of abstraction, which doesn't make sense to really implement but why shouldn't the props pass down all the same

Comment: @BrandonBell I don't see `<ThemeProvider />` in your App.js. What's more, you are using `makeStyles`, which is no longer supported in MUI v5.

Comment: oh ok yeah it's probably the version thing... it's from the default example...

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The MUI's `Drawer` is created out of the `id=root`. Because of this implementation you must handle `rtl` and `ltr` direction by yourself :(.

I fixed this issue with below codes:

1. At first I defined a theme:

```
const mainTheme = createTheme({
   ...
   direction: "rtl"
});
```

2. Used `ThemeProvider` to wrap my content and put my `CustomDrawer` in it:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme} >
.....
    <CustomDrawer
       anchor={mainTheme.direction == "rtl" ? "left" : "left"}
       style={{
                direction: mainTheme.direction
       }}
       dir={mainTheme.direction}
    >
   ......
    </CustomDrawer>
</ThemeProvider >
```

3. Finally my `CustomDrawer`'s code is:

```
const CustomDrawer = styledMUI(Drawer)(({theme}) => ({
    "& .MuiPaper-root":{
        left:theme.direction =="rtl"? "unset":"0",
        right:theme.direction =="rtl"? "0":"unset",
    }
}));
```

***Note:*** `styledMUI` is defined as below:

```
import {styled as styledMUI} from '@mui/material/styles';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).